# Get current user in view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication

I'm using django authentication to login the user:

```
def signin(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
                username = request.POST.get("username").lower()
                password = request.POST.get("password").lower()
                user = authenticate(username = username, password=password)
```

However, I can't seem to access the current user in any other view. In every template, I have access to the user, but I don't seem to access in the view itself. For example, in another route I want to be able to do the following:

```
def profile(request):
        skills = hasSkill.objects.filter(user__username=user.username)
        return render(request, "/profile.html", {"skills" : skills})
```

But I keep on getting an error that user is a Nonetype object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to access `user` through the `request` that you get. You'll use `request.user` Change your view to:

```
def profile(request):
        skills = hasSkill.objects.filter(user__username=request.user)
        return render(request, "/profile.html", {"skills" : skills})
```

Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests).

> Django uses sessions and middleware to hook the authentication system
>   into request objects.
>
> **These provide a request.user attribute on every request which
>   represents the current user.** If the current user has not logged in,
>   this attribute will be set to an instance of AnonymousUser, otherwise
>   it will be an instance of User.

Comment: wow, surprised I missed it considering it was that obvious. Thanks, Alex!

Comment: No problem, happens to all of us!